# Jackson deserialization with unknown dynamic properties

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a JSON string like:

```
"shipping_profiles": {
  "563": {
    "name": "name",
    "value": "value"            
  },
  "564": {
    "name": "name",
    "value": "value"            
  },
  "565": {
    "name": "name",
    "value": "value"            
  },
  "566": {
    "name": "name",
    "value": "value"            
  }
}
```

Now I am parsing it with **Jackson 2.0**.
I am trying to get a `List<shipping_profiles>` from the JSON string.

Is it possible?

Comment: Could you show to us how your POJO class looks like?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't want shipping_profiles to be an array? E.g. "shipping_profiles" : [ "563": { ... }, ...].

Comment: @Michał Ziober : I have not designed the POJO till now. Waiting for some help from you to design the POJO

Comment: @ Chris Kessel : Unfortunately , Yes. this is the final JSON string I am getting.

Comment: Could you tell me what these number mean? This is an entity ID or something else which you want to parse? Or you only need "name" and "value" properties?

Comment: @Michał Ziober This is an unique id. I dont need to do anything with those ids. I only need the "name" and "value" properties and get  a list of Object.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your `shipping_profiles` property doesn't look like array. It represent object with dynamic properties, so we should treat it like an object. If we do not know anything about properties we can use `@JsonAnySetter` annotation. Algorithm could looks like below:

1. Deserialize JSON into JSON-model classes.
2. Convert dynamic objects (maps) into app's POJO classes using ObjectMapper
3. Use app's POJO whenever you want.

Please see my example implementation. I hope, it help you solve your problem. Input JSON:

```
{
   "shipping_profiles":{
      "563":{
         "name":"name563",
         "value":"value563"
      },
      "564":{
         "name":"name564",
         "value":"value564"
      },
      "565":{
         "name":"name565",
         "value":"value565"
      },
      "566":{
         "name":"name566",
         "value":"value566"
      }
   }
}
```

Example program:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class JacksonProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        File source = new File("X:/test.json");
        Entity entity = mapper.readValue(source, Entity.class);
        ShippingProfiles shippingProfiles = entity.getShippingProfiles();
        List<Map<String, String>> profileMaps = shippingProfiles.getProfiles();

        List<Profile> profiles = new ArrayList<Profile>(profileMaps.size());
        for (Map<String, String> item : profileMaps) {
            profiles.add(mapper.convertValue(item, Profile.class));
        }
        System.out.println(profiles);
    }
}

class Entity {

    @JsonProperty("shipping_profiles")
    private ShippingProfiles shippingProfiles;

    public ShippingProfiles getShippingProfiles() {
        return shippingProfiles;
    }

    public void setShippingProfiles(ShippingProfiles shippingProfiles) {
        this.shippingProfiles = shippingProfiles;
    }
}

class ShippingProfiles {

    private List<Map<String, String>> profiles = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setDynamicProperty(String name, Map<String, String> map) {
        profiles.add(map);
    }

    public List<Map<String, String>> getProfiles() {
        return profiles;
    }

    public void setProfiles(List<Map<String, String>> profiles) {
        this.profiles = profiles;
    }
}

class Profile {

    private String name;
    private String value;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Profile [name=" + name + ", value=" + value + "]";
    }
}
```

Above app prints:

```
[Profile [name=name563, value=value563], Profile [name=name564, value=value564], Profile [name=name565, value=value565], Profile [name=name566, value=value566]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I got my json with dynamic property parsed with the way @michalziober provide.

```
"commandClasses": {
        "32": {
          "name": "Basic",
          "data": {
          "name": "devices.1.instances.1.commandClasses.32.data",
          "value": null,
          "type": "NoneType"
         },
         "38": {
          "name": "SwitchMultilevel",
          "data": {
          "name": "devices.1.instances.1.commandClasses.38.data",
          "value": null,
          "type": "NoneType"
         },
         "43": {
          "name": "SceneActivation",
          "data": {
          "name": "devices.1.instances.1.commandClasses.43.data",
          "value": null,
          "type": "NoneType"
         }
```

With this json I also need to save that dynamic property, so I add another List for storing it.

```
public class CommandClasses {

    private List<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private List<CommandClass> commmandClasses = new ArrayList<CommandClass>();
    private Logger logger = Logger.getInstance(CommandClasses.class);

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setDynamicCommandClass(String name, CommandClass cc) {
       logger.d("@ adding new CC : " + name);
       nameList.add(name);
       commmandClasses.add(cc);
    }

    public List<CommandClass> getCommmandClasses() {
        return commmandClasses;
    }

    public void setCommmandClasses(List<CommandClass> commmandClasses) {
        this.commmandClasses = commmandClasses;
    }
}
```

Now I can also access the field as id to send out request later.