# how to load Yaml file using VM argument?

Tags: java, yaml

Is there any way we can load `.yml` file using `VM argument`, like we load `.properties` file for log4j using `-Dlog4j.configuration`?

I looked for this but nothing useful found. All solutions are for Spring Boot. But I need to load `yaml` (from some directory which is not fixed) in an executable jar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse a yaml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25796637/parse-a-yaml-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. You can get any application parameters with

```
System.getProperty("my.property");
```

So if you start your application with

```
-Dmy.property=path/to/yaml/file
```

, in your code you can retrieve the value `path/to/yaml/file` as String and then you can load the file as YAML (for example, with SnakeYAML). The general case of loading YAML from a file is covered in SnakeYaml's [documentation](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation).