# how to read docker-compose.yml file in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker-compose, yaml

I need to read docker-compose.yml file inside my spring boot application. I only need to read services that I have defined in yml file. My docker-compose.yml file as below.

https://gist.github.com/pubudu94/9cc5c46606c9a497d61058b096326dfe

I only need to read services names such as [abc,qqqq]. I tried this tutorial.
https://dzone.com/articles/read-yaml-in-java-with-jackson
 but i don't want that much complex code for this small task. Do you have any suggestion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SnakeYaml for this.

Refer below thread for more info.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25797282/6572971