# How do I use a variable from an application.yml file in my normal code?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

For example, let's say that in my yml file I had a variable called indicator. And based on what the indicator variable's value was I want the code to do something different. How would I access the yml variable in the regular code and use it accordingly?

Comment: Refer this link: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-yaml this helped me understand this better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this:

```
@Value("${your.path.yml.string}")
private String x;
```

YML:

```
your:
  path:
    yml:
      string: hello
```

x will be "hello"

Comment: oh ok. when i tried that i got an error saying Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sampleService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sampleServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'indicator.operation' in value "${indicator.string}

Comment: use @Component in the class.

Comment: wait the class i'm using it in or do i have to create a class for the variable?

Comment: could be in the class you are using it

Answer (score 4):

1. You need to use Spring Expression Language which says we should write it as

```
    @Value("${spring.application.name}") 
    private String appName;
```

2. For Default value if key is not present in yaml/yml or properties file

```
    @Value("${spring.application.name: defaultValue}") 
    private String appName;
```

3. The last way you can fetch value is using environment object

```
    @Autowired  
    private Environment environment;
       
    String appName = environment.get("spring.application.name");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `@Value` annotation to any field in your beans.

```
@Value("$(path.to.your.variable)")
String myString;
```

Works with constructors as well.

```
public MyClass(@Value("$(path.to.your.variable)") String myString) {
```

Comment: what would the path be like? just the path to the yaml file where the variable is?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@Value` on fields or parameters to assign the property to some variable.

Property example:

```
@Value("${indicator}")
private String indicator
```

Parameter example:

```
private void someMethod(@Value("${indicator}") String indicator) {
    ...
}
```

Then you can use *indicator* as you want.

Note: the class where you use `@Value` should be a Spring Component

Answer (score 1):

With Spring-Boot, you have the file `application.yml` automatically provided for you. What you can do is adding a property in this file, for instance:

```
my.properties: someValue
```

Then, in one of your Spring Bean (either define with `@Component` or `@Bean`) you can retrieve this value using the annotation `@Value`. Then, do whatever you want with this variable.

For instance:

```
@Component
public class MyClass {

    @Value("${my.properties"}
    private String myProp; // will get "someValue" injected.

    ...


    // Just use it in a method
    public boolean myMethod() {
        if(myProp.equals("someValue") {
            // do something
        } else {
            // do something else
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is not to have a tight coupling between Spring and your "normal" code at all, but instead to use the normal Java features like constructors along with Spring `@Bean` methods:

```
class MyService {
    final String indicatorName;

    MyService(String indicatorName) {
        this.indicatorName = indicatorName;
    }
}
```

... in your configuration class...

```
@Bean
MyService myService(@Value("indicator.name") String indicatorName) {
    return new MyService(indicatorName);
}
```

Two notes for Spring Boot specifically:

- The `@ConfigurationProperties` feature allows you to map properties onto structured Java data classes and is typically cleaner than using `@Value` by hand.
- Always namespace properties that you define yourself to avoid future collisions with other libraries, so instead of `indicator.name` use `company.project.indicator.name`. I recommend looking at `DataSourceProperties` in Boot to see an example of how to set all this up.

More broadly, though, when you say that you want the code to "do something different", it sounds like the better option might be to have *different classes* that get activated under different circumstances. Both Spring profiles and Spring Boot auto-configuration help to do this.

Answer (score -2):

The problem statement can be re-defined as Configuration Management in Java.

You should have a component like ConfigManager that gets instantiated as part of your application start up. That component will read a properties file, a yaml in your use case. Subsequent app logic will fetch these values from the ConfigManager exposed as simple key/value pairs.

All that is left for you to identify how to read and parse values from yaml file. This is already answered here:
[Parse a YAML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25796637/parse-a-yaml-file)

Comment: This entire functionality is one of the core things Spring provides in the first place.

Comment: It is not mentioned anywhere in the question that spring is required (inspite of the tag). I guess - "To a man with a hammer, everything looks like a nail" :)

Comment: It's tagged `spring-boot` and he mentions `application.yml` by name.