# parse a complex json object in java which has some int value in one node

Tags: java, json

plz help me to parse below json.I am getting this json from one source but problem is it has one int value in one of the node which is item id value.
 `"28": { and "44": {` is there at node position and not able to parse it.

```
{
  "request": {
      "Target": "some target",
    "Format": "json",
    "Service": "some service",
    "Version": "2"
  },

"response": {
    "status": 1,
    "httpStatus": 200,
    "data": {
      "28": {
        "Offer": {
          "id": "28",
          "name": "some name",
          "description":"some data",
          "url": null,
          "url2": null,
        }
      },
      "44": {
        "Offer": {
          "id": "44",
          "name": "some name",
          "description":"some data",
          "url": null,
          "url2": null,
        }
      }
     }
    }
}
```

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17685508/jackson-de-serialiazation-with-unknow-dynamic-property

Answer (score 0):

define `'data'` as `HashMap<String,String>` if you are using jackson parsing

Comment: Thanks for your response.but if "data" will be in hash map then all the id values like 28 , 44 .... all will be key to the hash map and anagin inside 28 and 44 offer object will be there.i am not getting this point. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using Gson to parse Json to Java objects.
Here is an example.

First you need to create a class for wrapping `Request` and `Response` objects.

```
public class RootWrapper {

    private Request request;
    private Response response;

    // Getters && Setters
}
```

`Request` is the easy one.

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Request {

    @SerializedName("Target")
    private String target;

    @SerializedName("Format")
    private String format;

    @SerializedName("Service")
    private String service;

    @SerializedName("Version")
    private String version;

    // Getters && Setters
}
```

And here is `Response`. You must use a `Map` to hold "44" and "22".

```
import java.util.Map;

public class Response {
    private int status;
    private int httpStatus;
    private Map<String, OfferWrapper> data;

    // Getters && Setters
}
```

Since `Offer` object wrapped in an other object you must use a wrapper object.

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class OfferWrapper {

    @SerializedName("Offer")
    private Offer offer;

    // Getters && Setters
}
```

And your Offer object should look like this

```
public class Offer {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String url;
    private String url2;

    // Getters && Setters
}
```

And at last, you can convert given Json to java object.

```
final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
final RootWrapper rootWrapper = gson.fromJson(TEST_JSON, RootWrapper.class);
```

By the way, your json is not valid. There are unnecessary commas at the end of `url2` tags.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your info. Yes by mistake comma is there.