# Parsing and Mapping a JSON Object with Dynamic Properties

Tags: java, jackson

So through research on Stackoverflow, [especially this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17685508/jackson-deserialization-with-unknown-dynamic-properties), I've determined that I have a JSON object dictionary embedded in an otherwise working getter/setter setup. When I make a call to the API, the traditional getter/setters for the properties work well, but that's because I know what the names of the properties are. How can I get this working for unknown properties of an object called `errors`, and what format is this object in (`Map<String,List>`)?

API Response:

```
{
    "success":false,
    "response_code":1,
    "status_message":"One or more errors has occurred.",
    "errors":{
        "171":["Some error message."],
        "555":["Some other error message."]
    }
}
```

My POJO:

```
public class APIResponse {
    private boolean success;
    private int response_code;
    private String status_message;
    private Map<String, List> errors = new HashMap<>();
    ...
}
```

How can I set the getter/setters and the correct dictionary format (Looks like maybe it's `Map<String,List>`) so that I can start receiving this dynamic `errors` object?

I'm using an `Invocation.Builder` to parse out the API response into an object.

```
Response response= invocationBuilder.post(Entity.entity(APIRequest, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
APIResponse formattedResponse = response.readEntity(APIResponse.class);
```

Comment: Is "some error message" a json array or a json object?

Comment: It looks like an array of strings (But is only ever one string), the example is the exact format it's returned in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was a tiered one.

First, [the discovery that Moxy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29324520/7106420) just doesn't do maps was frightening, but rather reliving once I found that the be the issue. So I had to change my default serializer from Moxy to Jackson. This was done easily by changing the `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Second, my attempt had it a bit wrong, instead of:

`private Map<String, List> errors = new HashMap<>();`

I really needed:

`private HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>;`

Throwing the constructor right in line with it would always wipe out the data. Instead I just initialize the map and then created the normal getter/setters on the POJO.